# VB 2010 and app.config file and configuration file has been changed by another program

Tags: vb.net, app-config

I'm a beginner in Visual Studio, I'm dealing with app.config file.
I just want to ask you a little tip: what is the best way to update a value key several times in app.config file using Windows Forms. So far I've tried this:

Just before that the Form1 is closed, I update a value with the next code:

```
Dim config As Configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(Application.StartupPath & "\MyProyect.exe")
Dim aps As AppSettingsSection = config.AppSettings 
aps.Settings.Item("SomeKey").Value = 5 'just an example
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified)
```

Then the next form is open with:

```
Form1.Hide()
Form2.Show()
```

But when I try to save again a value in the same key in the new Form2 it throws me an error an the program freezes:

**The configuration file has been changed by another program.(C:\Users\RH\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MyProyect\MyProyect\bin\Debug\MyProyect.exe.config)**

Really I've searching for a solution, but it seems that I'm the only one with this kind of problem. Like I'd say I'm just a beginner. Could you please give me an advice?

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is this, if you check the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms134087.aspx) for the `config.Save` method, there is this statement,

> If the configuration file has changed since this Configuration object
>   was created, a run-time error occurs.

`Save` changes the file, so this leads me to believe that you can only call the save method once per instance of the `Configuration` object. So, this leads me to believe that this,

```
Dim config As Configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(Application.StartupPath & "\MyProyect.exe")
Dim aps As AppSettingsSection = config.AppSettings 
aps.Settings.Item("SomeKey").Value = 5 'just an example
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified)
aps.Settings.Item("SomeKey").Value = 15 'just an example
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified)
```

would fail on the second save, but then this,

```
Dim config As Configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(Application.StartupPath & "\MyProyect.exe")
Dim aps As AppSettingsSection = config.AppSettings 
aps.Settings.Item("SomeKey").Value = 5 'just an example
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified)
'reopen
config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(Application.StartupPath & "\MyProyect.exe")
aps = config.AppSettings 
aps.Settings.Item("SomeKey").Value = 15 'just an example
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified)
```

Would succeed.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to save some user configurable value?  In that case, the best case is to use a Settings file, which is similar to the app.config file, but is updatable during the application run.  In all truth, the values you put in a *.settings file get inserted into the app.config file, but the process of reading and updating is managed by the application.

I have an application that allows users to read files from a folder, and I save the last folder location in the Settings file.  The next time the application runs, I can read that value again for that specific user.

Here is some example code in C#:

```
//read the property on load    
if (Properties.Settings.Default["FileLocation"] != null 
    && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Properties.Settings.Default["FileLocation"].ToString()))
{
    DirectoryInfo dirInfo 
        = new DirectoryInfo(Properties.Settings.Default["FileLocation"].ToString());

    if (dirInfo.Exists)
        dlg.InitialDirectory = dirInfo.FullName;
}

//code removed for clarity
//....

//save on exit from method
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(dlg.FileName);
Properties.Settings.Default["FileLocation"] = fi.DirectoryName;
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

I translated it to VB.Net, but I apologize in advance as I haven't done VB.Net in a while, so you might want to sanity check it.  :-D

```
'read the property on load    
If (Properties.Settings.Default["FileLocation"] IsNot Nothing _
    AndAlso Not string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Properties.Settings.Default["FileLocation"].ToString())) Then
    Dim dirInfo as DirectoryInfo _
        = new DirectoryInfo(Properties.Settings.Default["FileLocation"].ToString())

    if (dirInfo.Exists) Then
        dlg.InitialDirectory = dirInfo.FullName
    End If
End If

'code removed for clarity
'....

'save on exit from method
Dim fi as FileInfo = new FileInfo(dlg.FileName)
Properties.Settings.Default["FileLocation"] = fi.DirectoryName
Properties.Settings.Default.Save()
```